# Running julia code on multiple machines

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have parallelized my algorithm using `pmap`. The performance improvement on one machine using the `-p` option is great. Now I would like to run on multiple machines.

I used the `--machinefile` option on julia start. It works but it launches only one process on remote machine. I would like to have multiple processes running on each machine. Option `-p` enables multiple processes only on the local machine. Is there a way to specify number of processes on remote machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Julia 0.3 you have to list the remote machines multiple times to open multiple Julia copies.

On Julia 0.4 (unreleased) you can actually put a count next to each address, [see this pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/7616/files).

Comment: Looking forward to 0.4 :)

Comment: Hah, I think we all are :D